# What is the simplest way to setup cron to send emails in ubuntu 16.04? Current approach (detailed in post) is not working

Tags: email, smtp, cron, ubuntu-16.04, alerts

My understanding is that:

- sSMTP has to be installed and configured
- MAILTO= has to be added on top of crontab

I have setup also installed the following instructions:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP

I've read other tutorials however they were from around 2009 and outdated.

Upon testing it as per the instructions I was not able to get it to work.

```
> echo test | mail -s "testing ssmtp setup" <email_address>
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

The email address I am trying to send emails from is a @gmail.com address.

Answer (score 1):

> mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

- Look in your logs.
- Find out what the exit status is.
- Investigate what it means.
- Apply changes to rectify.

Comment: Which log specifically do I check?

Answer (score 1):

First you should have an MTA installed on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install exim4
```

After that you should configure this MTA with smtp parameters (gmail in your case):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Choose **smarthost** usage and set a correct smtp (gmail smtp server for you) address. To ensure you've correctly configured the smtp server check **dc_smarthost** parameter in **/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf** file.

If you have to provide password authentication for the smtp server, check this [link content](https://www.howtoforge.com/exim-authenticated-smarthost) to do that.

If the smarthost configuration is correct the send command must work in a shell script:

```
echo "Mail Body" | mail -s "Suject" foo.bar@domain.tld
```

This is a basic way to send mail, to improve it: **man mail**

Comment: It would be useful to tell how to configure the package in CentOS since dpkg-reconfigure cannot be applied there.